# fopen not works in shared library

Tags: c, linux

Linux ubuntu 13.10 64

```
FILE *f = fopen(DATAFILE,"r");
if (f == NULL)
{
  syslog(LOG_ERR, "Cannot open data file %s, %s", DATAFILE,strerror(errno));
  return false;
}
```

This code work fine in main function when I create an exe program
But it fails in shared library with Permission denied error. Same file, same environment. The file access permission to DATAFILE is granted to all users

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Does this process also have the proper rights at every level of the path that leads to `DATAFILE`?

Comment: Is `DATAFILE` an absolute path, or relative?

Comment: You may want to use `strace` and you might also display the current working directory in the `syslog`

Comment: DATAFILE is an absolute path and all levels are accessible. I'm not familiar with strace but I will follow this track. Thanks

Comment: Result of strace, no meaning for me `7402  getcwd("/", 1024)= 2`
`7402  open("/var/data/test.dat", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)`

Comment: No problem with fopen. permission access restricted, probably, by ACLs. When I change file location under /etc/ it work fine.